# A comparison between heights and between grades

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I search for noetherian commutative rings having distinct prime ideals $P⊂Q$ with no primes between them, and where $\operatorname{grade}(Q)≠\operatorname{grade}(P) +1$, or $\operatorname{height}(Q)≠\operatorname{height}(P)+1$.

If $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, are the left and right sides of the above expressions  equal?
Thanks for cooperation!

Comment: is *Nagata*'s book, *Local rings*, Example.2 p.203 helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=K[x, y]/(x^2, xy)$,  $P=(x)$,  and $Q=(x, y)$. Both are prime ideals, there is no prime between them,  and both have grade zero.

For the height part of your question consider [Nagata's example](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JE) of a noetherian local domain which is not catenary and has dimension $3$. It contains a maximal chain of prime ideals $(0)\subset\mathfrak p\subset\mathfrak m$, and $3=\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak m>\operatorname{ht}\mathfrak p+1=2$.

Such a phenomenon can't occur in a Cohen-Macaulay ring: localize at $Q$ and recall that a Cohen-Macaulay ring is catenary.